# Powershell - Optional parameter in method of a class

Tags: powershell

In powershell functions i can have something like

```
Function myFunction {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$foo,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][string]$bar = "whatever"
    )
....
}
```

But this seems limited to functions - is there something similar for method?

```
class MyClass {
...
    [void]MethodA {
    Param(
    ....
```

dont works for me.
The interpreter complains about the missing '(' in the class method parameter list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding methods to classes works just like in most other scripting languages one might know. Instead of `[void]MethodA {Param()...}` you might want to add a block like described in [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/04/adding-methods-to-a-powershell-5-class/) [or here](https://www.petri.com/powershell-classes-part-3-using-methods):

```
class MyClass {
    #...
    [void]MethodA ($param) {
        #...
    }
}
```

As your title says optional parameters (but your question doesn't) a short word on that...

Usually you want multiple signatures for such cases. That means you create a method `MethodA($arg1, $arg2)` and a delegating method like `MethodA($arg1) {MethodA($arg1, $null)}`

Comment: And how can I add seriously optional parameter?

Comment: @Đonny Optional parameters [are, unfortunately, mandatory](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9701).